# Spring Boot transaction manager timeout

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions, transactional

I am using the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa from Spring Boot 1.4.2.

Everything works fine (@Entity classes discovery, datasource autoconfiguration, transaction autoconfiguration, EntityManager autoconfiguration).

I can not find where the Transaction timeout can bet set. Since I want to use Spring Boot as deep as possible, I do not wish to declare programmatically a transaction manager bean in any Config file.

The "[common application properties reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)" only mention timeouts for JTA Transaction managers, but none for the autoconfigure one for simple JPA use. Note that I am not looking for the jdbc query timeout.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If youre using the @Transactional annotation in the class using the EntityManager , you can just use e.g.: @Transactional(timeout = 10)

Answer (score 12):

It seems that newer versions supports it with

```
spring.transaction.default-timeout= # Default transaction timeout in seconds.
```